# vscode - letting javascript files know of each other

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I'm writing a simple circular collision detection program in javascript and the project structure of the files is like so:

[image]

basically there's no problem in code and the html runs fine in a browser, all the scripts are loaded and executed well as I've made this hierarchy in the `index.html`:

```
<script src="scripts/javascript/GLOBALS.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/javascript/utils.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/javascript/setup.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/javascript/Ball.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/javascript/main.js"></script>
```

but, when I access a function defined in utils.js in setup.js then, it says `function is undefined with a very disturbing red underline. How can I let vscode know of all the functions and variables up the hierarchy?

Comment: Use module and imports

Comment: Set in your package.json type to the value of module and then you can use import/export your functions from one file to another

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have mentioned the correct way to do this is with modules. Modules have been part of JavaScript standard since ES2015.

If you still don't want to use modules for whatever reason, it would require two steps to do this:

`index.js`:

```js
/* global Test */
/// <reference path="Test.js" />

const t = new Test();
```

and in `Test.js`:

```js
class Test {}
```

The triple slash `///` indicates to VSCode where these references can be found (for its intellisense) and the `/* global ... */` declarations tell eslint that there are globally defined variables that are being accessed.

Modules are definitely superior, but this should work as well.

Comment: yes, exactly what I was looking for, since I only needed if for intellisense

Comment: BTW, if you'd just add a sample format for `reference path` like, it should start from `./` or `../ ` or `/`

Comment: BTW, do you know of a rule to tell eslint that all variables outside of a functional or class scope are to be treated as global, you know instead of having to list them one by one? or even treat all variables in the file in the reference path

Answer (score 1):

In your package.json file you can set the key value pair **"type": "module"**.

Then you can use ECMAScript Modules. This means you can use the *export* keyword to export functions, variables or constants from one file and use *import* to import them in another file.

#### Exporting

```
export const name = 'square';

export function draw(ctx, length, x, y, color) {
  ctx.fillStyle = color;
  ctx.fillRect(x, y, length, length);

  return {
    length: length,
    x: x,
    y: y,
    color: color
  };
}
```

Or at the end of the file `export { name, draw, reportArea, reportPerimeter };`

#### Importing

```
import { name, draw, reportArea, reportPerimeter } from './modules/square.js';
```

Then you can use them in the file like this

```
let myCanvas = create('myCanvas', document.body, 480, 320);
let reportList = createReportList(myCanvas.id);

let square1 = draw(myCanvas.ctx, 50, 50, 100, 'blue');
reportArea(square1.length, reportList);
reportPerimeter(square1.length, reportList);
```

Here you can read more
https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules

Comment: these seem relatively new, I'd like to avoid all this long syntax if possible, can we disable just the importing modules error in vscode? just the importing, because all the other linting are very useful

Comment: this is related to your linter, you probably have a config file for your linter where you configurate it